# Is it possible to do a one way sync of iPhone voice memo's to a PC?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync

I've been a great iPhone lover from day one and don't possibly see me ever switching back to another mobile platform.

There's just one big con from my viewpoint, which is iTunes. I hate the interface, responsiveness and the massive amount of restrictions.

I want complete control over my hardware and applications, and iTunes is making this terribly hard for me.

Currently, I've got a couple of voice memo's recorded with the native iPhone OS 3.0 voice memo application. I want to transfer these memo's to my PC, but don't see any other way to do it apart from using the iTunes sync option. When I choose this option, however, my entire music library is removed, since the phone library can only sync with one iTunes instance.

**So the question is: *is there a way to manually transfer these voice memo's (and possibly other items) from my iPhone to my PC without forcing a two-way sync or deleting stuff from my phone?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few hacks online allowing you to sync your iPhone with multiple iTunes instances, however I must admit that I adapted to the single sync solution. I sync everything with iTunes on my Mac, which means I always have the information with me, either on my phone or my Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to say it, as a user of several Apple products, but if you want complete control over your hardware and applications, you probably shouldn't be using an Apple product. That's the way they work, often.

Comment: I have to agree on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the action button (the box with an arrow pointing out) and email it to yourself, or you could use itunes.